# What happens if I log in while under attack?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I know that you can't be attacked while you're online, but I was wondering what would happen if you log on during mid-attack from another player? Would their attack suddenly end or would it continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to log in while a raid is in progress, you won't be able to do any of the normal base activities until the attack is over.  It used to show a dialog with a countdown to when the attack was going to be over, but now it shows a live replay of the attack in progress.